# Configure two databases in spring boot for entity manager without entity classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I connected db2 database from `spring boot` and called stored procedures using entity manager. I didnt have any entity classes in my application. I just called stored procedures using Entity Manager reference.

Here application.properties

```
#DB2 dev database config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://server_nameXXX
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
```

And My Dao class is

```
EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    public SalesCloseEstimateDaoImpl(EntityManager entityManager){
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
   -----------------
    StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery =  entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(StoredProcedureName);
```

Here I didnt use any entity classes. Now I need to connect one more ms sql server, so how can I connect it. I have searched but all configuration having entity classes usage how can I write this configuration without entity classes?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: You don't need to use entity classes just configure datasource,entitymanager and transactionmanager

Answer (score 0):

if you're only calling store procedures it ins't necessary to have an entity manager in your application, i had the same problem, so i manage this way:

1. add the dependency and delete jpa and hibernate dependecies:

   org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-jdbc
2. Create a datasource file config: DataSourceConfiguration.java

@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db1")
    public DataSource bd1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db2")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap() {
        Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap = new HashMap<>();
        jdbcTemplateMap.put("bd1DataSource", new JdbcTemplate(bd1DataSource()));
        jdbcTemplateMap.put("bd1DataSource", new JdbcTemplate(bd1DataSource()));
        return jdbcTemplateMap;
    }

}
```

3. create your "repository":

   @Component @Slf4j
   public class DB1Repository {

   private final Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap;

   public DB1Repository(Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap) {
   this.jdbcTemplateMap = jdbcTemplateMap;
   }

   public YourClass callSP(int id){
   String storeProcedure = "USE [BD]\n" + //
   "EXEC [dbo].[store_procedure] @id";

   ```
    storeProcedure = storeProcedure.replace("@id", String.valueOf(id));
    YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();

    jdbcTemplateMap.get("db1").execute(storeProcedure, (PreparedStatementCallback<Object>) preparedStatement -> {
        preparedStatement.execute();
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            yourClass.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            yourClass.setName(resultSet.getInt("name"));
        }
    return yourClass;
    });
    return yourClass;
   ```

   }
   }
4. create your next "repository" reference to db2, and thats all!.